# Bootstrap App - Body of the app doesn't seem to respect col-sm-10 class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap MVC 5 app and I'd like to make a change to it so that the body only consumes 10 of the 12 columns and I'd like to create a  that consumes the remaining 2 columns for other uses. My _Layout.cshtml code is pretty standard and looks as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="visible-lg visible-md" src="~/Images/WebBirderFatbirder.png" title="WebBirder">
                @*@Html.ActionLink("WebBirder", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://www.fatbirder.com/">Fatbirder</a></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyContentDiv" class="container body-content col-sm-10">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <br/>
            <br />
            <br />
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div id="statusDiv" class="col-sm-2">
        This is the area I want to use for other purposes.
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

As you can see, in the div containing the id of 'bodyContentDiv' I added a class of 'col-sm-10'. This seems to have no affect though. The div with an id of 'statusDiv' does not appear to the right of the main body but appears at the bottom.

Comment: You should wrap your .col-xx-xx in a div.row . You should try too to replace col-sm-xx by col-xs-xx.   http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the Bootstrap Grid System, you should have a `.container > .row > .col-*-*` structure.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="bodyContentDiv" class="col-sm-10 body-content">
           @RenderBody()
           ...
        </div>
        <div id="statusDiv" class="col-sm-2">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the [Bootstrap Grid System Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more info on this.

> - Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or
>     `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.